# Localize XPages Websites

Tags: xpages

Some XPage Websites need to be localized. I found [this](http://[here][1]%20%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/notes-global-pt1/) IBM article `Helping customers globalize their Lotus Notes applications`. One needs an `Lotus Domino GLobal Workbench` app for this purpose.
The [DGW_Guidlines](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/uafiles.nsf/docs/dgw50/$File/DGW_Guidelines.pdf) PDF is from 1999.

Is it still the recommended way ?
Does it also support XPages ?

If not - what is the common way to do it nowadays ?

Comment: The global workbench was designed for classic Notes apps. In XPages you have globalization baked in in the form of property files. These can be processed with most translation workflow tools. Check Paul's links for details

Answer (score 3):

The out-of-the-box option for XPages is described on the [Domino App Dev wiki](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/UsingLocalizationOptions.htm). See also the slide deck from [IBM Connect 2014](http://www.slideshare.net/kjbrown13/bp208-pdf). More details can also be found in Mastering XPages 2nd Edition.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279559/xpage-localization-process-how-to-translate-properties-files-in-bulk) for alternatives.

Other developers have taken a more manual approach of using fewer properties files but looking up the values

Comment: Thanks Paul, I followed the `Domino App Dev wiki`. I need around an hour to read the wiki and test in Designer. It works perfect.